# Configured debug type "python" is not supported for VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have issues debugging with VS code. I have installed python for vs code extension and reloaded it several time. But when I tried to run in the debug mode, I have the following error

```
The debug type is not recognized. Make sure that you have a corresponding debug extension installed and that it is enabled.
```

My `launch.json` has the following contain

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "Python : Fichier actuel",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by uninstalling Python and Jupyter Notebook extensions in VS Code and then re-installing them. Note that Jupyter Notebook is now required to use the Python extension in VS Code.

Comment: I was using open source Codium and the Python extension was not installed out-of-the-box.

Comment: Uninstalling Jupyter seemed to fix it for me, but then the problem was back the next day when I started vscode again.

Comment: @ChrisProsser - same here. After closing/reopening vs code. No issues running the config though. Only being flagged in the edtor

Answer (score 8):

This issue is a VS Code bug, it is being solved in an [early Dec-2021 release (v1.63)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17952). The warning has no effect whatsoever, there are no real issues running the code.
So, don't pay attention to it, it will be fixed in a short time.

Edit note: Adding, removing, installing, or disabling/enabling the Jupyter Notebook and its related extensions seem to solve the problem but only until the next VS Code restart.

Comment: I can confirm that release v1.63 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. The easiest way for me to fix it, was to:

- go to the Python file in the file explorer,
- right click, and choose "run current file in interactive window".

After that selection, VSCode prompted me that

> X,Y,Z, will need to be installed and configured".

I did that, and then everything worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I think it came from using `virtualenvwrapper`:

when creating virtual environments using `mkvirtualenv` the virtual environment is not placed inside the project folder (e.g. in a folder .venv), but gathered in a central place defined by the `$WORKON_HOME` user environment, which has to be defined during installation of `virtualenvwrapper`.

So far, so good - but VSCode has to be told, where this central folder lies. At least this was what solved the problem for me. So:

- open the settings of the Python extension (search for `Python` (by Microsoft) and click on the gearwheel next to the Python icon -> Extension settings)
- in the search bar type `@ext:ms-python.python venv`
- in the User settings in section "Python: Venv Path" enter the directory where all your virtual environments lie (= `$WORKON_HOME`)

After that I restarted VSCode and it didn't complain anymore in the `launch.json` file (or in my case, the `.code-workspace` file), VSCode immediately found the python interpreter in the virtual environment and everything worked fine again.