# VS Code: Issues setting debugger up in venv

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I'm following the Python Flask [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) from Microsoft, but for whatever reason the debug part is just not working for me. I figured it would be way easier to record a short video showing the error I'm having and also, showing the steps I'm taking.

https://www.loom.com/share/8dfcf53e9c19468ea8a74281931a4fd4

Any help is massively appreciated! The video doesn't have any audio, it's just me showing what I see when setting up a venv into an existing directory and trying to do it from scratch while still having the same issue.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I just noticed I didn't showed the warning itself, it said:

> configured debug type 'python' is installed but not supported in this environment.(2)

Comment: Any helpful contents here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194481/configured-debug-type-python-is-not-supported-for-vs-code. Suggested 1) Un/install python and Jupyter notebook extension, 2) Downgrade VSCode version.

Comment: Thanks! I did went through that thread, and I think if I want to get it solved I need to Downgrade. I found an issue opened on the VS Code repo about the same situation, so I think it's indeed a bug. I'll live a little while with that thing there as I'm new to VS Code, so I might break something else trying to downgrade. 