# Configured debug type "python" is not supported for VS Code (remote explorer)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I get this error message:

```
Configured debug type "python" is not supported for VS Code
```

It happens when running code from the `remote explorer`.

On researching, it is a very similar issue as this problem:

[Configured debug type "python" is not supported for VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194481/configured-debug-type-python-is-not-supported-for-vs-code)

However, the difference is that the error **only arises** when I use the `remote explorer` which connects to GitHub repos.

I tried the proposed solutions to the previous question (given the similarity), but they did not work, so I am stuck here.

The same code runs perfectly fine in my file explorer.

So basically, this:

[image]

I wonder if somebody can resolve this, given the above?